# Trying to deploy Adobe Reader XI via GPO on Server 2012 R2 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, domain, deployment, adobe-reader

this is what I did:

1. Downloaded .exe from Adobe-ftp
2. successfully extracted with "AdbeRdr11010_de_DE.exe" -nos_ne
3. 'slipstreamed' the .msp into the .msi with klaus-hartnegg's tool
4. made a .mst with Adobe Customization Wizard
5. moved the whole folder to network share
6. I set the permissions of the folder for the computers to read and execute
7. made a computer-configuration-gpo (sorry for bad translation...german system)
8. added the .mst
9. restarted client several times
10. tried to enable logging https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246509

this is what is happening:

- win7-computer is showing installation message at boot for appr. 15secs
- eventlog shows installation failed with error %%1603
- appmgmt.log is not existing

I uninstalled Adobe Reader before and deleted a GPO for Adobe Reader that was never working, but I tried before and failed, too.

Comment: Does the application install correctly without the GPO?

Comment: Yes, even the created msi installs fine. I think it has something to do with the distribution.
BTW: is appmgmt.log only created in special cases, because it is not there.

Comment: 1603 is most likely a custom action that is failing.  You need to enable Windows Installer verbose logging per https://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300 and set it to: voicewarmupx.  Then check the Windows Installer log that is created.

Comment: Are you simply trying to bulk install Adobe Reader?  Use Ninite Pro.  www.ninite.com/pro

Comment: You'll need something to update  it once you've deployed it anyways.

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks! I am going to try this the day after tomorrow and report it.

Comment: Error 1334. The file 'acroext.exe' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file 'Data1.cab'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

Seems like it is not installing locally, too. I must have mixed something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not create a proper AIP as explained in http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/aip.html

Steps to successfully deploy Adobe Reader XI via GPO:

1. Download EXE from Adobe-FTP-Server
2. start a cmd with admin-rights
3. extract EXE: (see klaus-hartnegg.de/gpo/msi_acroread.html)
   e.g. AdbeRdr11002_en_US.exe -nos_oD:\AdobeReader -nos_ne
4. cd D:\AdobeReader
5. create AIP: (adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/aip.html)
   e.g. msiexec /a AcroRead.msi TARGETDIR=\yourserver...\Reader\11010
6. slipstreaming Patches: (adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/aip.html#acrobat-quarterly-update)
   e.g. msiexec /a \yourserver...\Reader\11010_de_DE\AcroRead.msi /p AdbeRdrUpd11010.msp
7. configure with Adobe Customization Wizard directly on NetShare:
8. create a new GPO on Domain Controller and choose 'advanced' to load the newly created MST-file in the 'Modifications'-tab
9. click OK and choose Computers to deploy to

BTW: as @GregAskew mentioned you can turn on logging if you run into problems